# reference to function before its defined

Tags: javascript, html

I have read that if you want to make it look like your site loads faster then you should put your javascript at the end of your html file like the following

```
<html>
<body>
</body>
<script>
//my awesome javascript functions go here because it lets things load faster 
//than if it was at the top
</script>
</html>
```

The problem is when I create buttons or use onChange events that call these functions.
How am I meant to keep my JS at the bottom of the page and have the JS defined for when it reads that the js function will need to be called?

For example

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" onChange="myfunction()"/>
</body>
<script>
function myfunction(){}
</script>
</html>
```

I did the code in pseudo code-ishly so you wouldn't focus on any of my syntax errors, but more focus on how I am meant to go about this.
When creating the page, it creates the html properly, but gives me a console error saying "myfunction" is not defined.
If I move the script part above the body this works, but it is recommended to keep it last to increase speed in page load.

Just a note I am not using jquery.

I originally thought this was a duplicate ([Javascript at the bottom, function call in the body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849188/javascript-at-the-bottom-function-call-in-the-body)) but it doesn't seem to answer my problem.

------------------------update----------------------------
using event listeners

```
<html>
    <body>
    <input type="text" id="myawesometext"/>
    </body>
    <script>
    function myfunction(){}
    element = document.getElementById('myawesometext');
    element.addEventListener("onChange", myfunction, false);
    </script>
    </html>
```

Comment: You can move the change handler also to the script tag in the bottom to seperate concerns. Thats one way of solving the problem and also keep concerns seperate.

Comment: In this approach with the scripts loaded last (which is considered best practice), you would probably use `addEventListener` instead of using the on-attributes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

Comment: Hi, just put it inside document.Load ;)

Comment: @christian314159 Hey, I updated my question. Is the way I suggested the proper way of doing it? Thanks for all the help everyone! Sorry about the easy questions!

Comment: That's the way, whereas the name of the event would just be "change" (with `addEventListener` you always omit the `on`). Be aware that there are some browser quirks, so depending on whether you have to support some old IE version, you might have to use slightly different syntax - and that's where a library like jQuery comes in very handy as it does that for you.